# Тень текста самим текстом

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Добрый вечер!
Нужно сделать то, что на картинке. Тень текста самим текстом. Хочется сделать более грамотно. Возможно у вас есть какие-тo предложения по этому поводу?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Например, так:

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: #e2cfce;
}

.text {
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 30px auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 40px;
  color: #3f3e45;
  z-index: 2;
}

.text:before {
  display: block;
  content: attr(data-text);
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  left: 0px;
  top: 20px;
  right: 0px;
  font-family: 'Marck Script', cursive;
  text-transform: none;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #b899a9;
  letter-spacing: 0.15em;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,700" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Marck+Script" rel="stylesheet">
<div class="text" data-text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
</div>
```

Выдержка из статьи про [свойство `content`](https://webref.ru/css/content):

**attr(<атрибут>)**

Возвращает строку, которая является значением атрибута тега указанного в скобках. Например, `a::after {content:attr(href)}` добавит после ссылки её адрес, т. е. значение атрибута `href`. Если указанного атрибута нет, то вернётся пустая строка.